# How to set a default value for reporting services textbox?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

I have a textbox in my .rdlc page which gets values from sql server. However, i want to add a default value to the textbox if the value is NULL. Currently, it shows nothing when the value from sql is NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways :-

1. Do it in the DataSource itself as mentioned by mason in the other answer. If you are using SQL Server, `ISNULL()` function will help.
2. You can use the `isnothing()` function. Ex `iif(isnothing(Field!FieldName.Value),"Default Value",Field!FieldName.Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ISNULL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function.

```
select username, ISNULL(firstname, "no name") from users
```